# 'among' or 'in'

Tags: grammar, expressions

I would like to rewrite the sentence

"Patents are territorial. Because patent laws and examination processes vary between countries, patents must be filed in countries of interest in methods established by authorities of those countries. As a result, a patent application for an invention in one country is filed either in the same format or in different formats in other countries.'

as following 
'It is because patents are territorial. Applications for an invention which have been filed in one country has to filed in other countries' authorities in terms of different patent laws and examination process among different countries. '

is it correct? Should I replace 'among different countries' by 'in different countries'?

Could you please give me some suggestions? please let me know, if you have any other advise about my sentence.

thanks in advance. 
best regards,
Alex

Comment: It may be  worth having a look at the dictionary definition of 'among', especially synonyms,  to help you decide whether its a good fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can be used interchangeably in this situation. Among is more like 'with' than 'in' though.

> It is because patents are territorial. Applications for an invention
>   which have been filed in one country has to filed in other countries'
>   authorities in terms of different patent laws and examination process
>   among different countries.

What you wrote was understandable but, as a native speaker, it should be more like this:

> Patents are territorial. Applications for an invention that has been
>   filed in one country must be filed for again in another country
>   because there are different patent laws and examination processes
>   among different countries.

'Because' is totally unnecessary at the beginning of an explanation, and you used 'authorities', which means law enforcement officers, where you should have used 'laws'. Plus there are a few other minor grammatical errors.

Comment: In your edited version, you don't file an invention in a country, you only file applications for it. So, it should be *have*, not *has* . . .

Answer (score -1):

“in” is the best option to choose as “among” is different in terms of meaning. As far as I know “among” is often used when comparing three or more things and etc.